Primeng p-dropdown Multiple component match error NG0300
I am new at Angular development.
I am using angular v17 and primeng v17. I want to add a component selector for p-dropdown like
@Component({
selector: 'p-dropdown[enum-select]',
templateUrl: './enum-select.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./enum-select.component.css'],
imports: [
    DropdownModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgIf,...
],
standalone: true}) export class MbsmEnumSelectComponent {....}

my template is like
<ng-template pTemplate="selectedItem" let-country>
    <div class="flex align-items-center gap-2" *ngIf="model">

        <div>{{ country.label | translate }}</div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-country pTemplate="item">
    <div class="flex align-items-center gap-2">

        <div>{{ country.label | translate }}</div>
    </div>
</ng-template>

And I want to use is like  <p-dropdown mbsm-enum-select  id="test"  [showClear]="true"  [options]="kullaniciTips" [(ngModel)]="queryModel.kullaniciTip"   styleClass="min-width-full"> </p-dropdown>
so I can use default ptoperties of p-dropdown and I don't want to implement all features of p-drowdown like form binding and ngModel and so on.
But when I use it I get an error on console

ERROR RuntimeError: NG0300: Multiple components match node with tagname p-dropdown:

What am I doing wrong?

Won't it be much easier if you define the component selector and use it: <enum-select></enum-select> instead of using attribute selector: <p-dropdown enum-select>?

I don't think your desired requirement is achievable. Each component has its unique selector and for your scenario, the HTML <p-dropdown mbsm-enum-select> is unable to resolve due to matching multiple selectors. If you are looking for a solution to split the mentioned HTML into separate component, probably this demo may help with ControlValueAccessor.

You cannot create dynamic selector names.
